# Nested if statement in .profile

Tags: bash

I have statement like this in .profile

```
if [ -z ${SBX_NAME+x} ] #Check for existence
then
       export SBX_NAME=      #DO NOTHING
else
      if [ "$PILLAR" =  "DEV"]
      then
            export SBX_NAME=$SBX_NAME
      else
            export SBX_NAME= #NO sandbox
      fi
fi
```

I need to check if `$SBX_NAME` exists, if yes check if `$PILLAR` equals DEV. But somehow it does not work the way it should, anyone knows how to fix it?
Since it is in .profile I do not know how to test it better ...

Comment: If you are actually using `bash`, use `.bash_profile` and use `[[ -v SBX_NAME ]]` to check if it is set.

Comment: @chepner what would be the correct way to write it in .profile?  it looks like the problem is in `if [ "$PILLAR" =  "DEV"]`

Comment: currently `$PILLAR' is DEV  and `$SBX_NAME` exists and has value, but returns that `$SBX_NAME` has no value

Comment: You can put `bash`-specific code in `.profile`, but be aware that shells other than `bash` might try to use `.profile`, which is why I suggested `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Double `[[ ]]` helped, also spacing is must between the condition statement and `]]`

`if [[ "$PILLAR" =  "DEV" ]]`